# I am trying to call displayUsers with an inline array containing the new user object that i added to users array

Tags: javascript, arrays, inline

//here is displayUsers

```
const displayUsers = (users) => {users.forEach((user) => {         
    const option = document.createElement("OPTION");  const name = 
    document.createTextNode(user.name);
    option.value = user.id; 
    option.appendChild(name);
    document.querySelector('select').appendChild(option);
    });
    };
```

//My user object added to users array

```
  var[user]=(results);
  console.log(user);
  users.push(user);
  console.log(users);`
```

//My main problem. This does not work

```
    displayUsers(new [users]);`
```

I expect the below result but I am not getting it. Any pointers, please?

**Add user object to our users array and then call displayUsers with an inline array containing the new user object.**

Comment: Shouldn't it just be `displayUsers(users[0])`? Or is `users[0]` a constructor function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to your instructions just call the function and make the parameter an array. so you will convert the object user to an array. So you will call the function this way:

```
displayUsers([user]); // converts user object to array and pass it to function
```

Answer (score 0):

Destructuring works when creating a variable - here, you'd have to use `users[0]`:

```
displayUsers(new users[0]());
```

This also assumes that `users[0]` is a constructor function - if not, then just do:

```
displayUsers(users[0]);
```